# list style image not working by external style sheet

Tags: css, html, list, stylesheet

I write this below Html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
ul{
list-style-image:url('img/grey.png');
}
</style>

<body>

<ul>
  <li>Coffee</li>
  <li>Tea</li>
  <li>Coca Cola</li>
</ul>

</body>
</html>
```

list created seccessfully, but when I want using external style sheet and changed the code I have problem.

code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styletest.css?version=2" ></head>

<body>

<ul>
  <li>Coffee</li>
  <li>Tea</li>
  <li>Coca Cola</li>
</ul>

</body>
</html>
```

style sheet:

```
ul{
list-style-image:url('img/grey.png');
}
```

image not show in second style.

thanks for any help.

Comment: That means your img path is wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to update the path to your image in your stylesheet. Paths in stylesheets are relative to the stylesheet.

You're using a relative path that starts in the directory it is defined in.

Your first, working, example suggests the following project structure.

```
img/
 └── grey.png
index.html
```

`img/grey.png` is defined in `index.html` so the relative path starts looking for a directory named `img` that `index.html` is in. It finds it because both `index.html` and the `img` directory are in the same directory. Then continues on down the path to the file.

Your second, non-working, example suggests the following project structure.

```
css/
 ├── styletest.css
 └── img/
      └── grey.png
index.html
```

`img/grey.png` is defined in `styletest.css` so the relative path starts looking for a directory named `img` that `styletest.css` is in, which is in the `css` directory. It doesn't find `img` because it's not in the `css` directory. It's a level up from the `css` directory, like below.

```
css/
 └── styletest.css
img/
 └── grey.png
index.html
```

To move up a directory level from a current directory you need to use `../`. Now the system will move up and out of the `css` directory and continue searching for the file from *that* directory and along the specified path.

Change from

```
list-style-image: url( 'img/grey.png' );
```

to

```
list-style-image: url( '../img/grey.png' );
```

Answer (score 0):

When you changed to your external stylesheet you also changed the "working directory" so your image url should be "../img/grey.png" rather than "img/grey.png". By adding ".." you will travel one directory up.

You could also make it a root relative referance by using "/img/grey.png".

However the cause of your issue is the added "css/" path. if you had placed the css file in the same directory as the html file you would have had no issues.

Answer (score 0):

Like dippas already said, the image path is wrong. The reason is that relative paths start at the location of the css file where the rule is defined. In your first example you are using inline css, so the path is relative to the document root. In your second example you are using an external css file in subfolder /css, so this is now the path, and the relative path `'img/grey.png'` don't work any more. `../img/grey.png` will no work.